# unmet dependency installing syslog-ng

Tags: apt, 22.04

I have a dependency problem when I want to install the latest version of syslog-ng from the latest version of ubuntu server 22.0.4.1. I haven't found any solution on the internet to resolve this dependency:

```
root@mylinux:/# sudo apt install syslog-ng
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 syslog-ng-core : Depends: libjson-c4 (>= 0.13.1) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
 syslog-ng-mod-sql : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Could anyone helpme with this?

My linux version:

```
root@mylinux:/# lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
```

Comment: try full-upgrading your system first, then install.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)